# Adding a SearchBar to a search A Class

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

So I would like to add a SearchBar to my tableView which is an RSS Feed, I have followed many tutorials and none have worked because it can't search the Custom Class that has been created.

I have used the RSS Feed from here: https://github.com/PrashantMangukiya/SwiftRSSReader

It has an RssRecord.swift containing:

```
class RssRecord {

    var title: String
    var description: String
    var link: String
    var pubDate: String

    init(){
        self.title = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.link = ""
        self.pubDate = ""
    }

}
```

And in the main ListViewController this is how I tell each cell what to have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rssCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    let thisRecord : RssRecord  = self.rssRecordList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = thisRecord.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = thisRecord.pubDate

    return cell
}
```

I'm having the problem when it comes to searching the tableView, how do I search this sort of Array, if it is an array?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing to search? I usually have a variable that is the content strings concatenated (`title + description + link`) and when I have to filter for a query, I just check if that concatenated string contains the query. That's very basic but usually good enough.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez So it would be searching whatever the user typed into the searchBar and would be searching only the titles, would you be able to show me some code to help, Thanks!